# Is there such thing as an 'active' adapter for DisplayPort to VGA?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, displayport

I know in the past I've had to use active adapters when I'm dealing with a graphics card with DVI-I/DVI-D ports to get them to work with old VGA monitors.

I'm wanting to know if when I'm buying an adapter for my graphics card's DisplayPort to VGA.

Can I just buy any old adapter, to convert DisplayPort to VGA, or do I need an active one (if they exist)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display port to VGA does require an active adapter, however it will get power from the port itself and does not require external power.

Further reading: [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort)

> **Analog VGA and dual-link DVI require powered active adapters to convert the protocol** and signal levels and do not rely on Dual-Mode. **VGA adapters are powered by the DisplayPort connector**, while dual-link DVI adapters may rely on an external power source (see Dual-mode).

Comment: I believe, by definition, all DP to VGA adapters are active, and powered from the DP source.  DP can not produce analog signals, so an active adapter is required to do that.